php time round up & round down
I am using the following function to round the time to closest 15 minutes.
function roundTime($time){

    $seconds = $time;
    $rounded_seconds = round($seconds / (15 * 60)) * (15 * 60);

    return date('H:i', $rounded_seconds) . "\n";
    
}

What I actually need it to be able to round UP or  round DOWN  to closest 15 minutes, OR 30 minutes of my choice. Separate functions can be used for each.
After searching for rounding up/down, I am aware of the functions floor and ceil but I can't understand how to use them with time?
For example, if I have the time of 14:05, I would like to be able to round it up to closes 15 min, for example 14:15, and to round up to closes 30 min, 14:30 I want to be able to decide weather to round up or down.
Instead of rounding to closest 15 min, I want to be able to round UP or round DOWN to closes 15 min, if that makes sense.
The code is used for clocking system. The employee needs to have full 15 minutes in order for it to count as overtime. For example, if they clock out at 14:26, they get paid until 14:15.

Could you give a few example of what you mean by: "What I actually need it to be able to round down and round up to closest 15 minutes, and 30 minutes."? Show us what your current function does, and what you want it to do instead. Please add these examples to the question.

Are you just looking for ceil($seconds / 900) * 900 ?

Do you mean something like this? https://3v4l.org/kXcCS ? The specification isn't 100% clear. Provide examples of input data, and the expected output in each case.

solution with int-arithmetic only: $rounded_seconds = intdiv($seconds+450,900)*900

I would like to be able to round it up to closes 15 min, for example 14:15, and to round up to closes 30 min...you want it to output both values? Or should the input be able to choose which rounding is applied? The specification is still ambiguous

Instead of rounding to closest 15 min, I want to be able to round UP or round DOWN to closes 15 min, if that makes sense...no, those both sound like the same thing.

The employee needs to have full 15 minutes in order for it to count as overtime. For example, if they clock out at 14:26, they get paid until 14:15...this sounds like you always want to round down, then? And in this example, where does rounding to 30 minutes come into it, as you mentioned before? Do we need to be given more than one example, to cover all cases?

If you want something fully flexible where you can choose the rounding interval and the direction, you can pass these options in as arguments to the function, perhaps like this:
function roundTime($timestamp, $interval, $direction){

    $rounded_seconds = 0;

    switch ($direction) {
        case "u": //round up
            $rounded_seconds = ceil($timestamp / ($interval * 60)) * ($interval * 60);
            break;
        case "d": //round down
            $rounded_seconds = floor($timestamp / ($interval * 60)) * ($interval * 60);
            break;
        default:
            echo "default";
    }

    return date('H:i', $rounded_seconds) . "\n";
    
}

$testTimes = [
    "2023-05-30 14:05",
    "2023-05-30 14:23",
    "2023-05-30 14:35",
    "2023-05-30 14:40",
    "2023-05-30 14:55"
];

foreach ($testTimes as $time)
{
    echo "base time: ".$time.PHP_EOL;
    echo "round up to 15 mins: ".roundTime(strtotime($time), 15, "u");
    echo "round up to 30 mins: ".roundTime(strtotime($time), 30, "u");
    echo "round down to 15 mins: ".roundTime(strtotime($time), 15, "d");
    echo "round down to 30 mins: ".roundTime(strtotime($time), 30, "d"); 
    echo PHP_EOL;
}

This test data will output:
base time: 2023-05-30 14:05
round up to 15 mins: 14:15
round up to 30 mins: 14:30
round down to 15 mins: 14:00
round down to 30 mins: 14:00

base time: 2023-05-30 14:23
round up to 15 mins: 14:30
round up to 30 mins: 14:30
round down to 15 mins: 14:15
round down to 30 mins: 14:00

base time: 2023-05-30 14:35
round up to 15 mins: 14:45
round up to 30 mins: 15:00
round down to 15 mins: 14:30
round down to 30 mins: 14:30

base time: 2023-05-30 14:40
round up to 15 mins: 14:45
round up to 30 mins: 15:00
round down to 15 mins: 14:30
round down to 30 mins: 14:30

base time: 2023-05-30 14:55
round up to 15 mins: 15:00
round up to 30 mins: 15:00
round down to 15 mins: 14:45
round down to 30 mins: 14:30

Live demo: https://3v4l.org/oqOTE

this worked! thank you!

You would have to add two parameters to your function: The wanted interval, 15 or 30 minutes, and whether you want to round down or up. Something like this:
function roundTime(int $seconds, int $intervalInMinutes, bool $roundDown)
{
    $functionName    = $roundDown ? 'floor' : 'ceil';
    $intervalSeconds = $intervalInMinutes * 60;    
    $roundedSeconds  = $functionName($seconds / $intervalSeconds) * $intervalSeconds;
    return date('H:i', $roundedSeconds) . "\n";
}

Live demo: https://3v4l.org/g75tA
It is very similar to the function you had apart from some optimizations.
